# Subsetting 2D NumPy Arrays

Tags: python, numpy, 2d, subset

hello im on the path of learning the python and i am struggling to understand this problem can you please help me to solve this problem

Print out the 50th row of np_baseball.
why the answer for this command is  [49, :]
From my perspective if the asking for the 50th it should be just [49] why there is additional :

Will be extremely glad for your respond

Comment: If you have a 2D array, `[49]` and `[49, :]` will do the same thing. `[49]` is correct.

Comment: How would you print the `5th` column? How is the row selection any different?

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy doc on slicing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html) states:

> If the number of objects in the selection tuple is less than N, then : is assumed for any subsequent dimensions.

So both versions are actually the same.

The example the documentation gives, is this:

```
x = np.array([[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]])
x[1:2]  # array([[[4],[5],[6]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using this `course`:

https://github.com/datacamp/courses-introduction-to-python/blob/master/chapter4.md

and looking at this block of code:

```
# baseball is available as a regular list of lists

# Import numpy package
import numpy as np

# Create np_baseball (2 cols)
np_baseball = np.array(baseball)

# Print out the 50th row of np_baseball
print(np_baseball[49,:])

# Select the entire second column of np_baseball: np_weight_lb
np_weight_lb = np_baseball[:,1]

# Print out height of 124th player
print(np_baseball[123, 0])
```

Notice that the next line selecting a column uses the `[:,1]` notation:

```
np_baseball[:,1]
```

Here the ':' is required to identify/slice the first dimension, rows. In `np_baseball[49,:]`, the ':' does the same thing, slicing the 2nd dimension.  But as a shorthand, trailing dimensions don't need to be specified, so `np_baseball[49]` is fine.

When writing instructional answers I like to include the trailing slice even it isn't required by the code.  I think it makes things clearer to (most :) )
human readers.

Answer (score 0):

```
# baseball is available as a regular list of lists

# Import numpy package
import numpy as np

# Create np_baseball (2 cols)
np_baseball = np.array(baseball)

# Print out the 50th row of np_baseball
print(np_baseball[49:50])

# Select the entire second column of np_baseball: np_weight_lb
np_weight_lb=np_baseball[:,1]

# Print out height of 124th player
print(np_baseball[123, 0])
```